# SSRS Bar Chart Conditional Formating

Tags: sql, reporting-services, sqlreportingservice

I am trying to conditional format a bar in my Bar Chart.

[image: Bar Chart]

I am comparing Planned Time VS Actual time and I want to set a conditional format to display different colors `IF Actual is less than or Equal to Planned then show me RED else GREEN.` 
I am unable to find a way to do this. Please Help!

I tried `SWITCH` and `IIF` functions but nothing happens. Same of my code attached.

```
=iif(Fields!ActualDuration.Value <= Fields!PlannedDuration.Value, "Light Coral", "Dark Sea Green")
```

I expect the bars to change color according to my criteria.

Comment: can you provide a picture of your chart? as well as relevant information related to the chart? such as the fields you are using for your x and y values?

Comment: Can you also edit your question to show what property you are trying to use to set the bar colour.

Comment: Hi Guys, apologies for not supplying sufficient info. I am new to this :)
I have added an image of my chart. In the Series Properties for 'Actual Duration' - this is where I am trying to do a conditional format on that bar in particular. my IIF shows the formatting i am trying to do.

Comment: Are you assigning that expression to the `Fill` property of the `Series` properties? Also, is your bar chart displaying the sum of the values? In which case your expression will need to use a sum calculation as well.

Comment: Hi Chris. Yes I assigned the expression to the `FILL` property of the `series`. and yes my values use `SUM`.

Comment: @ChrisLatta thanks I have tried it with `sum` and it worked!! Appreciate your help.

Comment: @Trisha I'm glad you got it working. I've added this as an answer so future visitors can see the working solution.

Answer (score 0):

Because your chart sums the values, your expression for the Series `Fill` property also needs to use SUM:

```
=iif(SUM(Fields!ActualDuration.Value) <= SUM(Fields!PlannedDuration.Value), "Light Coral", "Dark Sea Green")
```